# Post from Android to CSV with Columns

Tags: php, android, json, csv

i want to post from Android to a CSV File correctly. Now the php posts the Question, Answer and the User in one column. With \n i can switch to a new row in the CSV File. \t doesn't work.

Now it look like this:

**Column1**

Question1Answer1User1

Question2Answer2User2
...

It should view like this:

**Column1| Column2| Column3**

Question1| Answer1 | User1

Question2| Answer2 | User2

..

The Java Code inside the Android App.

```
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dbHandler.getAllStimmungen().size(); i++)  {

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("question"+i, dbHandler.getAllStimmungen().get(i).getQuestion()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("answer"+i, dbHandler.getAllStimmungen().get(i).getAnswer()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user"+i, httpHandler.getContact(1).getuserName()+"\n"));

        }
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,
                    "POST", params);

        return null;
    }
```

The PHP Code

```
<?php

      $timestamp = date("d.m.y-H:i:s");  
      $filename= 'myTextFile-'.$timestamp.'.csv';
      $lastIndex = 0;

     // receive data from app's http request
     $data=($_POST);
     // write data from my android app to a text file
     file_put_contents($filename,$data);
    ?>
```

Sorry for my English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV stands for Comma Separated Value. It means that columns are separated by **commas**. Said that, a new line character `\n` switches to a new row and has nothing to do with columns. You have to put commas between every single value in the csv file.

```
column1,column2,column3, \n
value1,value2,value3, \n
value11, value22, value33,
```